# MySQL Query of catalog_product_super_link filtered by attribute_set_id

Tags: database, query, attribute-set

I want to export all fields from the `catalog_product_super_link` table, but filtered to exclude any products that have have a certain `attribute_set` (31 in this case).

This post ([MySQL Query filtered by attribute_set_id](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58709/mysql-query-filtered-by-attribute-set-id)) gets me part of the way there, but unfortunately I'm a novice with MySQL and could do with any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```sql
select * from catalog_product_super_link where product_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity where attribute_set_id = 31);
```